# How can I get a Bootstrap column to span multiple rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following grid with Bootstrap.

I'm not sure how I'd create the box (number 1) that spans two rows. The boxes are generated programmatically in the order they are laid out. Box 1 is a welcome message.

[image]

Any ideas on the best way to go with this?

Comment: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem, You can nest the Bootstrap gridsystem.

Comment: So create 2 rows, rather than 3, nesting the 2 rows within the first row? This could be problematic when the boxes are generated programatically.

Comment: No idea if it would work, but would adding the `pull-left` class to all the boxes work? it won't make box 1 the same height as 2 + 4, but it should allow it to work when you set the height.

Comment: Hailwood, put that as an answer if you can, if not I'll paste my code. It worked ... at least on Chrome. Need to test it in other browsers.

Comment: @Hailwood infact, no pull left is needed. Just setting a height on the first element works.

Comment: Any idea how is this done in Bootstrap 5.x?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

**For Bootstrap 3:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">1
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="well">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="well">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**For Bootstrap 2:**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><div class="well">1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div></div>
    <div class="span8">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">2</div></div>
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">3</div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">4</div></div>
            <div class="span6"><div class="well">5</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See the demo on JSFiddle (Bootstrap 2): http://jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/52/

Comment: How would you make boxes four and five fill the row's height as box one grows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: This is example does not quite work, the first column's bottom edge is slightly misaligned with the rest.

Comment: This is a great answer, but what if box 5 needed to extend into row 3 as well, and more-so, dynamically?

Comment: @Misha'el That's pretty simple, just do what he did for for box 1 and apply it to box 3/5. There should be 3 columns of equal size, the one's on the outside would contain just 1 row, the one on the inside two rows.

Comment: how could we get 1 to be the same height as 2 & 4 without using line breaks - eg if we want it to be an image or rotating images?

Answer (score 25):

Like the comments suggest, the solution is to use nested spans/rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">1</div>
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">2</div>
                <div class="span4">3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">4</div>
                <div class="span4">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">6</div>
        <div class="span4">7</div>
        <div class="span4">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than the code-only answer, IMO.

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 alert alert-primary">
     1
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 alert alert-primary">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 alert alert-primary">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 alert alert-primary">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 alert alert-primary">
        5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4 alert alert-primary">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 alert alert-primary">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 alert alert-primary">
    8
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the part regarding how to span rows has been answered thoroughly (i.e. by nesting rows), but I also ran into the issue of my nested rows not filling their container. While flexbox and negative margins are an option, a much easier solution is to use the predefined `h-50` class on the `row` containing boxes 2, 3, 4, and 5.

> **Note:**
>   I am using `Bootstrap-4`, I just wanted to share because I ran into
>   the same problem and found this to be a more elegant solution :)

Comment: I used your solution to fix the container not filling. I tried h-100 on the side that was not filling

Answer (score 0):

The example below seemed to work. Just setting a height on the first element

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="span4" style="height: 100px"><h1>1</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>2</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>3</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>4</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>5</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>6</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>7</h1></li>
    <li class="span4"><h1>8</h1></li>
</ul>
```

I can't help but thinking it's the wrong use of a row though.