# How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap. How can I make three columns all the same height?

Here is a screenshot of the problem. I would like the blue and red columns to be the same height as the yellow column.

[image: Three bootstrap columns with the center column longer than the other two columns]

Here is the code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
        some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
        catz
        <img width="100" height="100" src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 panel" style="background-color: blue">
        some more content
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745966/twitter-bootstrap-responsive-block-heights/

Comment: The example on Bootstrap breaks responsiveness  Eduard. The flex `.row` is missing `flex-wrap: wrap;`. Here's an example of it working with responsiveness: http://codepen.io/bootstrapped/details/RrabNe/

Comment: Possible Workaround – A Transparent image 1 pixel wide in the other columns.   This new one pixel width image matches the pixel height of the cats pic in the above example.  (May not work or be practical in your situation)

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, we can use the card for the same

Comment: the same way you make any block element a specific height?

Comment: working solution - https://www.codeply.com/p/bCpAPuS0LL

Answer (score 1173, accepted):

## **LATEST SOLUTION (2022)**

**Solution 4 using Bootstrap 4 or 5**

Bootstrap 4 and 5 use Flexbox by default, so there is no need for extra CSS.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gzm3L456/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red">
          some content
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: yellow">
          catz
          <img width="100" height="100" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100/">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: green">
          some more content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 1 using negative margins (doesn't break responsiveness)**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/1195/)

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden; 
}

[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

**Solution 2 using table**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/1192/)

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Solution 3 using flex** added August 2015. Comments posted before this don't apply to this solution.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nV3Ua/1821/)

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Think of it as the column being sucked into negative space. If you remove the overflow you'll see what's going on.

Comment: It works but has a problem if you need to absolutely positioning some element at the bottom: it's hidden by the overflow. Nested elements neither can't determine the actual visible height, without javascript.

Comment: @mjolnic good point. I'd like to find a better solution. I would have thought height 100% and display block might help.

Comment: it works in Firefox for me. Can you share your code?

Comment: If targeting the bootstrap column class specifically you should probably use an anchor ^ instead of a wildcard *. Using ^ will say that the class must start with col- where as the wildcard shown will match any class with col- anywhere in the string, possibly having undesired effects on styles where you may have used the convention col-.  (i.e. stuff-col-morestuff).

Comment: @LiquaFoo I agree but that's how bootstrap's selector is.

Comment: It works only with single line of blocks. For more block, it ads them in right side again until it brakes view zone.

Comment: @Popnoodles I can share my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000554/firefox-workaround-for-position-for-table-cell-element

Comment: This is working but my col-xs-12 is being ignored now.. How do i fix that?

Comment: Solution 1 can make width problems

Comment: Nice answer, with some caveats. Solution 1 disables the float and therefore breaks the bootstrap grid responsive behavior. Solution 2 (explained in greater depth in http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) doesn't show the bottom border (as it is clipped somewhere in the padding space).

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same problem. But after I tried the solutions, the column does not seems to be responsive. How to fix that?

Comment: Solution2 is responsive in my case but not the first one who occured some bug with bootstrap 3

Comment: I found a problem with solution 2: if there are elements with attr `id="xxx"` and users jump to the ID, contents above the element fail to display ([demo](http://pastie.org/9945803): paste the codes to a local html file, open it with ".../xxx.html#p3").   Solution 1 seems working fine, hope I won't find any issue with it.

Comment: @Notflip, I faced the same issue that "col-xs-12" doesn't make the next "col" to next line. My workaround is to apply solution 1 only to >= small device, as `@media(min-width:768px) { Solution 1 }`

Comment: Non of this solutions working at all.
1) destroys bs3 grid responsive not working since float:none
2) this solution isn't doing cols same size in responsive, here is demonstration: http://www.bootply.com/SmpoLAKqO1

Comment: Actually there are two thing what you could want, one is simple same col height without responsive, for this is best solution 2. Other one is to avoid jumping of col if text change height of one col to another, for this is best this solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/24747063/1269774.
If you want both, use javascript or flexbox or write your own grid using table.

Comment: in case of two columns when resize browser screen (on mid, sm etc) first columns hides... why ?? how to fix it

Comment: +1 Only for the second solution because it does not break the Bootstrap responsiveness. Any answer that does is useless when dealing with *Bootstrap*.

Comment: Solution ! did work for me. But I had to add the `!important` to margin.
Like this: `margin-bottom: -99999px !important;`

Comment: Solution 3 breaks row responsiveness.

Comment: These are all great examples for equal height columns although in this situation they all break the bootstrap grid framework. You should never do this explicitly to the row and column classes. Add your own class. The first one, while effective for fluid layouts is not good for responsive layouts as it applies all columns height to the height of the `.row` even if their not on the same row. The second one is missing styles and should not use BS columns as table cells. Tables are meant to use `border-spacing` while bootstrap `col-` classes use padding for their spacing. Using together wont work.

Comment: @Popnoodles you should add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the third example to enable responsiveness. You also will want to add display: flex; flex-direction: column; to the column class. If you are going to use .row  and not a custom class, you'll need to provide a fallback for older browsers changing the display flex back. Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/bootstrapped/full/RrabNe/)

Comment: I tried to make it out each method, but none of them work, here is my demo: [DEMO](http://demo.vrs-factory.pl/gl/)

Comment: @bwillis what does exactly do `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` in the column class? It seems to do nothing noticeable.

Comment: The 3rd solution is close, but in IE 11 the stacked divs seem to be too wide, and in FF the stacked divs have different widths.

Comment: Solution 1 hides the bottom border.

Comment: I prefer solution 2, and I add width: 100% for .row

Comment: @LoganG. ^ does not work for this class =" test col-md-2"

Comment: @HakamFostok These solutions have worked for 100s of others hence the upvotes. Feel free to post a new question with your bad code so that someone can advise where you have misunderstood.

Comment: None of the solutions, that work for 100s of others, work against *your* code, yet, despite the principal of Occam's razor, your wish is to downvote this answer multiple times. Hardly fair.

Comment: Solution 3: flex-wrap: wrap breaks on safari-mobile. I removed it and it works for me

Comment: Negative margin works the best.
The other two solutions break the responsive property (will not wrap on small screen)

Comment: Solution 3 doesn't work in Safari. `.row::before { display: block; }` fixes that but I'm not sure why.

Comment: `table-cell` or `negative margins` [don't really work](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-equal-height-columns-d07bc934eb27) when it comes to responsive design

Comment: Hello... no solutions worked for me. Can you see the snippet here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794658/how-to-set-all-elements-inside-a-row-to-be-the-same-height

Comment: @jstuardo that's because you're doing something else. You have cards and rows and div inside the columns, which are 100%, but aren't setting anything to height 100% to fix that.

Comment: I had to use flex-direction: inherit; in the columns as well

Answer (score 414):

## Update 2021

### **Bootstrap 4 + 5**

Flexbox is now used by default in Bootstrap 4 (and Bootstrap 5) so there is no need for the extra CSS to make equal height columns: https://www.codeply.com/go/IJYRI4LPwU

Example:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **Bootstrap 3**

**Best approach for Bootstap 3.x** — using CSS **flexbox** (and requires minimal CSS)…

```
.equal {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[Bootstrap same height flexbox example](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/127827)

To only apply the same height flexbox at specific breakpoints (responsive), use a media query. For example, here is `sm` (768px) and up:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

This solution also works well for multiple rows (column wrapping): https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/gCEXzPMehZ

**Other workarounds**

These options will be recommended by others, but [**are not a good idea**](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-equal-height-columns-d07bc934eb27) for responsive design. These only work for simple single row layouts w/o column wrapping.

1. Using [**huge negative margins & padding**](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/6mwUqfimQN)
2. Using [**`display:table-cell`**](https://www.codeply.com/go/GDZz7SjPwd) (this solution also affects the responsive grid, so a `@media` query can be used to only apply `table` display on wider screens before the columns stack vertically)

Comment: You can use a media-query to only apply the flexbox on larger/wider devices. I updated the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Cn6fA6LuTq

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I have created [a pen](http://codepen.io/justin-lau/pen/wapqdE/?editors=110) to demonstrate similar effects on a form using flexbox.

Comment: @ZimSystem Your code in Codeply doesn't work in Safari 10.0.3 / OSX http://take.ms/bj31b

Comment: It's a known Safari bug with flexbox: 
proof: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137730

Comment: @Stanley the comment about "no longer responsive" is old and irrelevant.

Comment: And, how is that? It works for me at and least 194 other people ;-)

Comment: What could be the possible reasons for these styles not to work in some cases?

Comment: The first 2 links don't work any more: "Application error"

Comment: This is the only fix that worked for me. Thanks Zim this is great!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, and I've tried quite a few. Thank you for this detailed post!

Answer (score 86):

No JavaScript needed. Just add the class `.row-eq-height` to your existing `.row` just like this:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
    kittenz
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: blue">
    some more content
  </div>
</div>
```

Tip: if you have more than 12 columns in your row, the bootstrap grid will fail to wrap it. So add a new `div.row.row-eq-height` each 12 columns.

Tip: you may need to add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css" />
```

to your html

Comment: flexbox-based. Does not work in IE8 or 9, nor Android 2.x http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Note: getbootstrap.vn is not "Bootstrap". It's a 3rd party project.

Comment: This seems to be integrated in bootstrap v4 though.

Comment: I included the correct CSS (from the .vn site) but it messes everything up.  it's based on flex

Comment: Great...plugin hell.

Comment: Cool, but this stylesheet include additional red and bordered styles to .col classes - this is not cool :(

Comment: NOT working in Bootstrap 4. this selector comes from somewhere else but is not part of bootstrap4

What worked for me is Solution 3) above with a slight change from flex to grid in the column selector


    .row {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display:         flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .row > [class*='col-'] {
      display: grid;  //here
      flex-direction: column;
    }

Comment: Works for me on bootstrap 3

Answer (score 72):

**To answer your question this is all you need [see full responsive demo with prefixed css](https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/RrabNe):**

```css
/* Using col-xs media query breakpoint but you can change 481 to 768 to only apply to col-sm and above if you'd like*/

@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
    .flex-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-row > [class*='col-'] {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .flex-row.row:after, 
    .flex-row.row:before {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Codepen]

**To add support for thumbnail content flex within flex columns like the screenshot above also add this... Note you could do this with panels as well:**

```css
.flex-row .thumbnail,
.flex-row .caption {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-text {
    flex-grow: 1;
}    
.flex-row img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

While flexbox doesn't work in IE9 and below you can use the demo with a fallback using conditional tags with something like [javascript grids](https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Grids) as a polyfill:

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]>

<![endif]-->
```

As for the other two examples in the accepted answer... The table demo is a decent idea but is being implemented wrong. Applying that CSS on bootstrap column classes specifically will without a doubt break the grid framework entirely. You should be using a custom selector for one and two the tables styles should not be applied to `[class*='col-']` that have defined widths. This method should ONLY be used if you want equal height AND equal width columns. It is not meant for any other layouts and is NOT responsive. We can make it fallback however on mobile displays...

```html
<div class="table-row-equal">
<div class="thumbnail">
    Content...
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
    Content...
</div>
</div>
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){
    .table-row-equal {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-spacing: 30px 0px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    .table-row-equal .thumbnail {
        float: none;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 1%;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the first demo in the accepted answer which implements a version of the [one true layout](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/example/equalheightopera8fix) is a good choice for some situations, but not suitable for bootstrap columns. The reason for this is that all the columns expand to the container height. So this will also break responsiveness since the columns are not expanding to the elements next to them, but the entire container. This method will also not allow you to apply bottom margins to rows any longer and will also cause other issues along the way like scrolling to anchor tags.

For the complete code see the Codepen which automatically prefixes the flexbox code.

Comment: That is the only one answer that actually worked for me. The 3 top rated answers were just a waste of time

Comment: Glad somebody found it useful. I definitely wasted way too much time creating that demo! One thing to note when using this and flexbox in general is that not all browsers are created equal. It is a pretty new concept and there are some quirks with it still depending on your layouts, so just make sure you do some cross browser testing before using it live.

Comment: Also if you do run into any issues with my method in the demo, I'd love to hear about it so I can make sure to fix it or add your example.

Comment: @bwillis Had to edit the masonry example to use `.masonary-row > [class*="col-"] ` to not break inner cols and added a breakpoint at 992px to have another column, but apart from that the Masonry works like a charm, kudos!

Comment: Yes this is the only answer here that works and is responsive. Make this the accepted answer.

Comment: Looks good, but unfortunately it doesn't work in Safari 9.1 on MacOS :-(

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @TheSchecke I will check it out today and update.

Comment: @TheSchecke here is the fix. As far as I know this works in all flexbox supported browsers now. Please let me know if I'm wrong. http://s.codepen.io/bootstrapped/debug/pboJNd. The problem had to do with the `row:after, row:before` having display: table set which apparently Safari doesn't like.

Comment: Just a heads up that this breaks really badly on the iPad's Safari browser

Comment: Sorry to hear that @MatthewLock. I just tested on my IPad Air IOS 8.1 with latest safari and it works on that. I was also able to test on on crossbrowsertesting.com using iPad mini retina with Safari 7 and that seems to be working fine too. [Here's the results](https://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/ic0b282d4f9e833b/screenshots/z8266ad2bb0f78ea5d4a/zd10b4bbdee1604c1c52) of that test. Can you provide the iPad and Safari version you are using? I'd love to try to get this fixed asap or at least put a comment in the answer as I know a lot of people are using it.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I will check that out.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D which link? They don't seem to be expired as far as I can tell.

Comment: Safary issue fixed with a help of ::before and ::after pseudo!)

Thanks a lot man!)

Comment: Came back for the same question more than two years later, not disappointed I commented/voted for this answer the first time, still perfectly fine and problem fixed within a few minutes!

Comment: This answer is da bom!  The only one that worked for me consistently, and on iPad Safari (iOS 12).

Answer (score 44):

You only show one row so your use case may be limited to just that.  Just in case you have multiple rows, this plugin - [github Javascript-grids](https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Grids) - works perfectly!  It makes each panel expand to the tallest panel, giving each row potentially a different height based on the tallest panel in that row. It's a jquery solution vs. css, but wanted to recommend it as an alternative approach.

Comment: The only solution that really works and it doesn't break responsiveness

Comment: Does this allow you to specify that the columns should be square - or just all the same height?

Comment: @niico 14 - its been awhile since I've used this, but in my application the requirement is that the elements in each row were the same height, but the height might vary from row to row.  Since the height is a function of the elements in the row, if your element height is equal to their width, then they should present as squares.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to make this work in any browser, use javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var heights = $(".panel").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".panel").height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Have one div class="row" with variable number of panels each of class "col-md-4" which should give me 3 columns and unknown number of rows, depending on number of items I want to list. This JS worked and requires minimal change in my HTML/CSS, as opposed to various CSS thingies I tried. Only thing I changed was to mark all my column panels with additional class, i.e. "same-height-panel" and then use $(".same-height-panel") instead of $(".panel")

Comment: The only solution that worked for me after one day of experimenting with css stuff.

Comment: This is a good solution, but `.ready()` is not the right time to call it - it should be called on `.load()`

Comment: @jave.web If you think that this is a good solution, please give it a thumbs up. Thanks

Comment: Use `window.onload = function() {...function content above...}` instead. This works better.

Comment: +1 Just like many others have said, the above solution seems to be a cleaner approach which does not temper with the css file.

Answer (score 21):

I tried alot of the suggestions made in this thread and on other pages but no solution worked 100% in every browsers.

So I experimented quite some time and came up with this.
**A complete solution for Bootstrap Equal Height columns** with the help of flexbox **with only 1 class.** *This works in all major browsers IE10+.*

**CSS:**

```
.row.equal-cols {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row.equal-cols:before,
.row.equal-cols:after {
  display: block;
}

.row.equal-cols > [class*='col-'] {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row.equal-cols > [class*='col-'] > * {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row equal-cols">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To support even more versions of IE you can, for example, use https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height and target all child columns of `.equal-cols`. Like this:

```
// Create a check for IE9 (or any other specific browser).
if(IE9) {
  $(".row.equal-cols > [class*='col-']").matchHeight();
}
```

Without this polyfill the columns will behave as usual Bootstrap columns so which is a quite good fallback.

Answer (score 17):

From official documentation. Maybe you can use it in your case.

> When you need equal height, add .h-100 to the cards.

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
  <div class="col">
   <div class="card h-100">
     <div>.....</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   <div class="card h-100">
     <div>.....</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Simplest answer (Works with Bootstrap >4)

Answer (score 10):

I'm surprised I couldn't find a worthwhile solution here late 2018. I went ahead and figured it out a Bootstrap 3 solution myself using flexbox.

Clean and simple example:

[image: Example of matched column widths in Bootstrap 3]

HTML

```
<div class="row row-equal">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-equal">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-equal">
        <img src="//placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-equal">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  padding: 2em;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-equal {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col-equal {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

View working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5kmtfrny/

Answer (score 9):

You can use inline-flex as well which works pretty good and may be a little cleaner than modifying every row element with CSS.

For my project I wanted every row who's child elements had borders to be the same height so the borders would look jagged. For this I created a simple css class.

```
.row.borders{
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While it succeeds at making all the contents in the row the same height; This breaks the responsiveness of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 9):

```
.row-eq-height {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display:         flex;
 }
```

From:

http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/equal-height-columns.css

Answer (score 8):

If anyone using bootstrap 4 and looking for equal height columns just use `row-eq-height` to parent div

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4<br>this is<br>a much<br>taller<br>column<br>than the others</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="border: 1px solid grey;">.row.row-eq-height &gt; .col-xs-4</div>
</div>
```

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/

Comment: I think this would be the best answer

Answer (score 7):

cheeky jquery solution if anyone's interested. Just make sure all your cols (el) have a common classname...works responsively too if you bind it to $(window).resize

```
function equal_cols(el)
{
    var h = 0;
    $(el).each(function(){
        $(this).css({'height':'auto'});
        if($(this).outerHeight() > h)
        {
            h = $(this).outerHeight();
        }
    });
    $(el).each(function(){
        $(this).css({'height':h});
    });
}
```

### **Usage**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   equal_cols('.selector');
});
```

---

Note: This post has been edited as per @Chris' comment out that the code was only set the last highest height in the `$.each()` function

Comment: This is understated - simple and small yet will resize all columns without needing to have a fixed number of columns in a row. Nice one!

Comment: This isn't working, cause you set the last biggest height in the each function. If the third column is the highest column, column 1 and 2 aren't getting the right height.. You have to set the last line "$(this).css({'height':h});" after the each function. I will do an edit.

Answer (score 7):

Some of the previous answers explain how to make the divs the same height, but the problem is that when the width is too narrow the divs won't stack, therefore you can implement their answers with one extra part. For each one you can use the CSS name given here in addition to the row class that you use, so the div should look like this if you always want the divs to be next to each other:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height-xs">Your Content Here</div>
```

For all screens:

```
.row-eq-height-xs {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

For when you want to use sm:

```
.row-eq-height-sm {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .row-eq-height-sm {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

For when you want to md:

```
.row-eq-height-md {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .row-eq-height-md {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

For when you want to use lg:

```
.row-eq-height-lg {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .row-eq-height-md {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on a comment, there is indeed a simpler solution, but you need to make sure to give column info from the largest desired width for all sizes down to xs (e.g. `<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">`:

```
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: You made that a lot more complicated than you needed to :) ` Just use `flex-wrap: wrap;` then you don't need all the separate ones... unless you specifically want them.

Comment: this fails on iPad Safari

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm very late but now you can use the "min-height" style attribute to achieve your purpose.

Answer (score 5):

So yes, Bootstrap 4 does make all the cols in a row equal height, however if you are creating a border around the content inside the row you may find that it appears like the cols are not equal heights!

When I applied `height: 100%` to the element inside the col I found that I lost my margin.

My solution is to use padding on the col's div (instead of a margin on the inner element). Like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 py-4">
            <div class="h-100 border round">
                        ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code example uses Bootstrap 4.1 to create a set of nine boxes with a border

Answer (score 4):

```
.row.container-height {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row.container-height>[class*="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

where .container-height is the style class that has to be added to a .row styled element to which all its .col* children have the same height.

Applying these styles only to some specific .row (with .container-height, as in the example) also avoids applying the margin and padding overflow to all .col*.

Answer (score 4):

Best out there:

### [Reflex - Docs](https://reflexgrid.com/)

Works with Bootstrap

**Update:**

1. Include the CSS
2. Update your code:

```css
/*!
 *
 * Reflex v1.0
 *
 * Reflex is a flexbox grid which provides a way to take advantage of emerging
 * flexbox support while providing a fall back to inline-block on older browsers
 *
 * Built by Lee Jordan G.C.S.E.
 * email: ldjordan@gmail.com
 * github: https://github.com/leejordan
 *
 * Structure and calculations are inspired by twitter bootstrap
 *
 */

.reflex-order-12 {
  -webkit-order: 12;
  -ms-flex-order: 12;
  order: 12;
}

.reflex-order-11 {
  -webkit-order: 11;
  -ms-flex-order: 11;
  order: 11;
}

.reflex-order-10 {
  -webkit-order: 10;
  -ms-flex-order: 10;
  order: 10;
}

.reflex-order-9 {
  -webkit-order: 9;
  -ms-flex-order: 9;
  order: 9;
}

.reflex-order-8 {
  -webkit-order: 8;
  -ms-flex-order: 8;
  order: 8;
}

.reflex-order-7 {
  -webkit-order: 7;
  -ms-flex-order: 7;
  order: 7;
}

.reflex-order-6 {
  -webkit-order: 6;
  -ms-flex-order: 6;
  order: 6;
}

.reflex-order-5 {
  -webkit-order: 5;
  -ms-flex-order: 5;
  order: 5;
}

.reflex-order-4 {
  -webkit-order: 4;
  -ms-flex-order: 4;
  order: 4;
}

.reflex-order-3 {
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}

.reflex-order-2 {
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}

.reflex-order-1 {
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

.reflex-order-0 {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
}

.reflex-container {
  display: inline-block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: -0.31em;
  *letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: -0.43em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.reflex-container *,
.reflex-container:before,
.reflex-container:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  white-space: normal;
}

.reflex-container *:before,
.reflex-container *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="reflex-col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
}

.reflex-item {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

_:-ms-fullscreen,
:root .reflex-item {
  width: 100%;
}

.reflex-col-12 {
  width: 100%;
  *width: 99.9%;
}

.reflex-col-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666666%;
  *width: 91.56666666666666%;
}

.reflex-col-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333334%;
  *width: 83.23333333333335%;
}

.reflex-col-9 {
  width: 75%;
  *width: 74.9%;
}

.reflex-col-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666666%;
  *width: 66.56666666666666%;
}

.reflex-col-7 {
  width: 58.333333333333336%;
  *width: 58.233333333333334%;
}

.reflex-col-6 {
  width: 50%;
  *width: 49.9%;
}

.reflex-col-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%;
  *width: 41.56666666666667%;
}

.reflex-col-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  *width: 33.23333333333333%;
}

.reflex-col-3 {
  width: 25%;
  *width: 24.9%;
}

.reflex-col-2 {
  width: 16.666666666666664%;
  *width: 16.566666666666663%;
}

.reflex-col-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333332%;
  *width: 8.233333333333333%;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .reflex-col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
    *width: 91.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
    *width: 83.23333333333335%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
    *width: 66.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
    *width: 58.233333333333334%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
    *width: 41.56666666666667%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    *width: 33.23333333333333%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
    *width: 16.566666666666663%;
  }
  .reflex-col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
    *width: 8.233333333333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .reflex-col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
    *width: 91.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
    *width: 83.23333333333335%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
    *width: 66.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
    *width: 58.233333333333334%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
    *width: 41.56666666666667%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    *width: 33.23333333333333%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-3 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
    *width: 16.566666666666663%;
  }
  .reflex-col-sm-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
    *width: 8.233333333333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .reflex-col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
    *width: 91.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
    *width: 83.23333333333335%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
    *width: 66.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
    *width: 58.233333333333334%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
    *width: 41.56666666666667%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    *width: 33.23333333333333%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
    *width: 16.566666666666663%;
  }
  .reflex-col-md-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
    *width: 8.233333333333333%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .reflex-col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
    *width: 91.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
    *width: 83.23333333333335%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
    *width: 74.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
    *width: 66.56666666666666%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
    *width: 58.233333333333334%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
    *width: 49.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
    *width: 41.56666666666667%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
    *width: 33.23333333333333%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
    *width: 24.9%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
    *width: 16.566666666666663%;
  }
  .reflex-col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
    *width: 8.233333333333333%;
  }
}

.reflex-wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.reflex-wrap-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.reflex-direction-row-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.reflex-direction-column {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.reflex-direction-column-reverse {
  -webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.reflex-align-start {
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.reflex-align-end {
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.reflex-align-end [class*="reflex-col-"] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.reflex-align-center {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.reflex-align-center [class*="reflex-col-"] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.reflex-align-baseline {
  -webkit-align-items: baseline;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.reflex-align-baseline [class*="reflex-col-"] {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.reflex-align-content-start {
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.reflex-align-content-end {
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.reflex-align-content-end [class*="reflex-col-"] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.reflex-align-content-center {
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.reflex-align-content-space-between {
  -webkit-align-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.reflex-align-content-space-around {
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.reflex-align-self-stretch {
  -webkit-align-self: stretch;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.reflex-align-self-start {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.reflex-align-self-end {
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  align-self: flex-end;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.reflex-align-self-center {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  align-self: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.reflex-align-self-baseline {
  -webkit-align-self: baseline;
  align-self: baseline;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.reflex-justify-start {
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.reflex-justify-end {
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.reflex-justify-center {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.reflex-justify-space-between {
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.reflex-justify-space-around {
  text-align: justify;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.reflex-item-margin-sm {
  margin: 0 0.25em 0.5em;
}

.reflex-item-margin-md {
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;
}

.reflex-item-margin-lg {
  margin: 0 1em 2em;
}

.reflex-item-content-margin-sm * {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
}

.reflex-item-content-margin-md * {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.25em;
}

.reflex-item-content-margin-lg * {
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.reflex-img {
  display: inline-block;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.reflex-item-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="reflex-container reflex-wrap">
  <div class="reflex-col-xs-12 reflex-col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
    some content
  </div>
  <div class="reflex-col-xs-6 reflex-col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
    kittenz
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/13/Matrona.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="reflex-col-xs-6 reflex-col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: blue">
    some more content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

here is my solution (compiled CSS):

```
.row.row-xs-eq {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

.row.row-xs-eq::before {
  content: none;
}

.row.row-xs-eq::after {
  content: none;
}

.row.row-xs-eq > [class^='col-'] {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row.row-sm-eq {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .row.row-sm-eq::before {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-sm-eq::after {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-sm-eq > [class^='col-'] {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row.row-md-eq {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .row.row-md-eq::before {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-md-eq::after {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-md-eq > [class^='col-'] {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row.row-lg-eq {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .row.row-lg-eq::before {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-lg-eq::after {
    content: none;
  }

  .row.row-lg-eq > [class^='col-'] {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

So your code would look like:

```
<div class="row row-sm-eq">
  <!-- your old cols definition here -->
</div>
```

Basically this is the same system you use with `.col-*` classes with that difference you need to apply `.row-*` classes to the row itself.

With `.row-sm-eq` columns will be stacked on XS screens. If you don't need them to be stacked on any screens you can use `.row-xs-eq`.

The SASS version that we do actually use:

```
.row {
  @mixin row-eq-height {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0;

    &::before {
      content: none;
    }

    &::after {
      content: none;
    }

    > [class^='col-'] {
      display: table-cell;
      float: none;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }

  &.row-xs-eq {
    @include row-eq-height;
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    &.row-sm-eq {
      @include row-eq-height;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
    &.row-md-eq {
      @include row-eq-height;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
    &.row-lg-eq {
      @include row-eq-height;
    }
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/12za60xq/)

---

**Note:** mixing `.col-xs-12` and `.col-xs-6` inside a single row would not work properly.

Comment: This is good. My solution is the same. And there is a possibility to have equal height columns with standard Bootstrap's 30px gaps between columns using `border-spacing` and negative margins.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with using Solution 1 while appling it on only column in rows. Would like to improve Solution 1.

```
 [class^="col-"]:not([class*="-12"]){
      margin-bottom: -99999px;
      padding-bottom: 99999px;
  }
```

(Sorry, can't comment Popnoodles's anwer. I have not enough reputations)

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a quick, easy solution - if you have a relatively consistent set of block content setting a min-height on the div that is a bit bigger than the largest block can be easier to implement.

```
.align-box {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**03/19/2019**

**Bootstrap 4 Equal Height Solution **

[Bootstrap Utilities/flex for equal height](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)

[Live example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/ashikjs/pen/YgOwzo)

**Equal height by bootstrap class with parent div fixed `height` or `min-height`**

```
<div class="d-flex align-content-stretch flex-wrap" style="min-height: 200px">
    <div>Flex height test text for example , Flex height test text for example </div>
    <div>Flex item</div>
    <div>Flex item</div>
    <div>Flex item</div>
 </div>
```

```css
.bd-highlight {
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.15);
}
.fixed-height-200 {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br><br><br>
<div class="d-flex align-content-stretch flex-wrap fixed-height-200">
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item <br> 1111111111</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight bg-danger">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight bg-info">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight bg-light">Flex item <br> 1111111111</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item <br> 1111111111</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item <br> 1111111111</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight bg-primary">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you give me Negative Vote. can you make a Comment for it ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my method, i have used flex with some changes in media query.

```
  @media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .fsi-row-xs-level {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .fsi-row-sm-level {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .fsi-row-md-level {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .fsi-row-lg-level {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

then added the classes to the parent which were required.

```
<div class="row fsi-row-lg-level fsi-row-md-level">
<div class="col-sm-4">column 1</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">column 2</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">column 3</div>
</div>
```

I am using responsive breakpoints because flux usually hampers the bootstrap standard responsive nature.

Answer (score 2):

I use this super easy solution with `clearfix`, which doesn't have any side effects.

Here is an example on AngularJS:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="item in list">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>
    <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 2" class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    <div ng-if="$index % 2 == 1" class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
</div>
```

And one more example on PHP:

```
<?php foreach ($list as $i => $item): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <?php if ($i % 2 === 1): ?>
        <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This does not make your columns all the same height, though.

Comment: For me wanting to have columns at the same height/place in row it is a solution

Answer (score 2):

I searched for a solution to the same problem, and found one just worked !! -
with almost no extra code..

see https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-equal-height-columns-d07bc934eb27
for a good disuccuion, and with the resposne you want in the bottom, with a link.

https://www.codeply.com/go/EskIjvun4B

this was the correct responsive way to for me...
a quote:
...
3 — Use flexbox (best!)

As of 2017, the best (and easiest) way to make equal height columns in a responsive design is using CSS3 flexbox.

```
.row.display-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.display-flex > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and simply use:

```
div class="container">
   <div class="row display-flex .... etc..
```

Answer (score 1):

If it makes sense in your context, you can simply add an empty 12-column div after each break, which acts as a divider that hugs the bottom of the tallest cell in your row.

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">Some content</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      Lots of content! Lots of content! Lots of content! Lots of content! Lots of content! 
   </div>
   <div id="spacer-div" class="col-xs-12"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">More content...</div>
</div><!--this You forgot to close -->
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not answer the question he asked!

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    div.equal-height-sm {
        display: table;


        > div[class^='col-'] {
            display: table-cell;
            float: none;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    }
}

<div class="equal-height-sm">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">Test<br/>Test<br/>Test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">Test</div>
</div>
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/njcnex83/embedded/result/

Adapted from several answers here. The flexbox-based answers are the right way once IE8 and 9 are dead, and once Android 2.x is dead, but that is not true in 2015, and likely won't be in 2016. IE8 and 9 still make up 4-6% of usage depending on how you measure, and for many corporate users it's much worse. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

The `display: table`, `display: table-cell` trick is more backwards-compatible - and one great thing is the only serious compatibility issue is a Safari issue where it forces `box-sizing: border-box`, something already applied to your Bootstrap tags. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

You can obviously add more classes that do similar things, like `.equal-height-md`. I tied these to divs for the small performance benefit in my constrained usage, but you could remove the tag to make it more generalized like the rest of Bootstrap.

Note that the jsfiddle here uses CSS, and so, things Less would otherwise provide are hard-coded in the linked example. For example @screen-sm-min has been replaced with what Less would insert - 768px.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4 option2">
            <p>left column </p>
            <p>The first column has to be the longest The first column has to be the longes</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 option2">
            <p>middle column</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span4 option2">
            <p>right column </p>
            <p>right column </p>
            <p>right column </p>
            <p>right column </p>
            <p>right column </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.option2 { background: red; border: black 1px solid; color: white; }
```

**JS**

```
$('.option2').css({
    'height': $('.option2').height()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd just add that the answer given by Dr.Flink can also be applied to a Bootstrap 3 `form-horizontal` block - which can be very handy if you want to use background colours for each cell. In order for this to work for bootstrap forms, you would need to wrap the form contents which just serves to replicate a table-like structure.

The example below also provides the CSS which demonstrates an additional media query allows Bootstrap 3 to simply takeover and do it's normal thing on the smaller screen(s). This also works in IE8+ .

Example:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 control-label">My Label</label>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

```
.form-wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.form-wrapper .form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

.form-wrapper .form-group .control-label {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}

.form-wrapper .form-group label + div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .form-wrapper {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .form-wrapper .form-group {
    display: block;
  }
  .form-wrapper .form-group .control-label {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .form-wrapper .form-group label + div {
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the columns inside a div

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: red">
  some content
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: yellow">
  kittenz
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 panel" style="background-color: blue">
  some more content
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did not work for me with a button in one of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this do through flex-box

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.col {
 background: blue;
 padding: 30px;
}

.col.center {
 background: red;
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">Left</div>
  <div class="col center">Center</div>
  <div class="col">Right</div>
</div>
```

Live JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/spsn4fnq/

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap 4 way of dealing with equal height columns, if you have cards as columns, is by using the `card-deck` class in a container div of the cards, then all the cards inside that div will appear as columns with the same height.

Answer (score -4):

Just checking through bootstrap documentation and I found the simple solution for the problem of column same height.

Add the extra clearfix for only the required viewport

```
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
```

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">This is a long text</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">This is short</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block">This is a long text</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Short</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Long Text</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Longer text which will push down</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">Short</div>
```

Please refer to http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Answer (score -5):

You can use below code

```
var heights = $(".row > div").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get(),
maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
$(".row > div").height(maxHeight);
```

Answer (score -7):

alot of css here...

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Get height of original column you want to match
   var box-height = $('.panel:nth-child(1)').outerHeight();

   // Output same height on particular element or element(s)
   $('.panel').height(box-height);

});
```

Really simple code no need to play with css, although all options above are perfectly usable.

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7andqqgk/)

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of CSS here because the question is tagged css and not javascript.  Don't post JS solutions to problems that can be solved with pure CSS.  In 99% of cases, the performance is worse.