# Complex bootstrap spanning grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Got a headache with complex spanning grid using bootstrap.

There are portrait and landscape blocs into 5 columns but they all have the same surface except the bloc number 1 that only got the same width.

It become complex when two portrait blocs shares the same row. Moving content with margin, is not suitable.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Box Spanning Multiple Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/bootstrap-box-spanning-multiple-rows)

Comment: On your link, if cell number 5 is higher and take 2 columns, how the next row will be collaps the like numbers 5/6 on mine

Answer (score 0):

here you go: this is the [fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygn56vth/)

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
        <div class="well">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="span8">
            <div class="span12"><div class="well">2</div></div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8">
                <div class="well">3</div>
                <div class="well">6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4"><div class="well">4<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <div class="well">7<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
        <div class="well">14<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="well">8</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="well">9</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well">
                    10<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="well">11</div>
                <div class="well">12</div>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <div class="well">
                    13<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row-fluid">
             <div class="span6">
                <div class="well">15</div>
            </div>
             <div class="span6">
             <div class="well">16</div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

you are not completely free on the panel sizes using span, if you want a more precise result you should use custom percentages on the div width.