# Bootstrap: Auto-adjustable grid layout with different item sizes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am working on a project that need to display items by 4 columns grid.

Like this:

[image]

So I put `col-3` class to my items.

But some items are important, that I need to display it with twice width and height.

So I changed that item class to `col-6`.

Now it looks like this:

[image]

I can use table instead but it's not media friendly...

Is there a way to make it look like this without messing up the div structure?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [CSS grid](https://learncssgrid.com/)? I think it should be much easier to use in your case than bootstrap grid.

Comment: Bootstrap's grid system is not made that you could expand some item in multiple rows. It is a row based system. The problem that you have described would be a perfect task for css grid -> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Bootstrap column to span multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/how-can-i-get-a-bootstrap-column-to-span-multiple-rows)

Comment: I've seen that question. It solved by nesting the row and col classes to achieve that. Which is not very efficient and completely messed up the div structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the grid system to keep your actual structure which is not yet implemented in boostrap.

see for more information : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ http://gridbyexample.com/

mind the support too https://caniuse.com/#search=grid

The idea is to set a grid of 4 columns and make some of your elements spanning through 2 colums and 2 rows. 
CSS to use for a  grid child:

```
grid-row:auto /span 2;
grid-column:auto / span 2;
```

demo, second or third & fith

```css
section {
  float: left;
  border:solid;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0.5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);  
  
  grid-template-rows:repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  counter-reset: divs
}

div {
  background: teal;
  counter-increment: divs;
  min-height: 10vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: white;
}

div:before {
  content: counter(divs)
}

section:first-of-type div:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: auto /span 2;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

section+section div:nth-child(3),
section+section div:nth-child(5){
  grid-row: auto /span 2;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

or span through the grid on hover only  on hover :

```css
section {
  width:40%;
  margin:auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap:0.5em;
  padding:0.5em;
  counter-reset:divs
}
div {
  background:teal;
  counter-increment:divs;
  min-height:10vw;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:5vw;
  color:white;
}
div:before {
  content:counter(divs)
}
div:hover{
  grid-row:auto /span 2;
  grid-column:auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: This code is so elegant and perfectly solved my problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by nesting bootstrap grid system.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col col-sm-3">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col col-sm-12">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-12">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-6">2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col col-sm-12">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-12">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
        <div>
            6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
        <div>
            7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4">
        <div>
            8
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

refer to this answer [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/how-can-i-get-a-bootstrap-column-to-span-multiple-rows)

Comment: You should always include the essentials instead of posting direct links

Comment: That kinda work but should have a better way to acheive it.