# Merge columns in Bootstrap vertically

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i simply want to join two columns in Bootstrap vertically. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an illustration of what i mean:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/16390370/12189828 for guidance on using nested spans/rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-6">
     <div class="row " >
         1.
     </div>
     <div class="row ">
      2.
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 ">
    3.
  </div>
</div>
```