# How to create grid fractional layout with elements spanning multiple rows with Bootstrap 5 grids?

Tags: html, grid, bootstrap-5

I know how I would like my UI to look and I have managed to sketch it with pure css grid layout. Preview: https://jsfiddle.net/oa5t3m14/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeVOy.jpg

Code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        div {
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 10px
        }
        textarea {
            border-style: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div
    style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 12fr 1fr; grid-gap: 10px; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; border-style: none; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <div style="grid-column: 1 / span 2; grid-row: 1">Link1 Link2 Link3</div>
    <div style="grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2">Text area title 1</div>
    <div style="grid-column: 1; grid-row: 3">
        <textarea style="resize: none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="p-3" placeholder="Text area 2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: 2; grid-row: 2">Text area title 2</div>
    <div style="grid-column: 2; grid-row: 3">
        <textarea style="resize: none; height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="p-3" placeholder="Text area 2"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: 1 / span 2; grid-row: 4">Footer</div>
</div>
</html>
```

But I would like to use use Bootstrap as much as possible. I have tried to recreate the same design with Bootstrap but with no success. I followed this advice: [How can I get a Bootstrap column to span multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/how-can-i-get-a-bootstrap-column-to-span-multiple-rows)

I bet there is a quite obvious solution to this but I'm new to the web design and it got me stuck.

Comment: https://dev.to/hoomanbahreini/how-to-use-half-and-quarter-columns-using-bootsrap-4-grid-system-3e3p#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20achieve%20this%2C%20I%20created%20a,file%20or%20use%20one%20of%20the%20following%20CDNs%3A
check this. may be it helps